# Read/Write Shapefiles .shp stored in AWS S3 from AWS EC2 using python

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am  using the below code on my local CLI python window which work  but unable to perform on EC2 (Amazon Linux 2),Please help me finding the solution as i have a tried many approaches from internet .

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd 
gdf1=gpd.read_file("s3://bucketname/inbound/folder/filename.shp")
gdf2=gpd.read_file("s3://bucketname/inbound/folder/filename.shp")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([gdf1, gdf2]))
gdfw =gdf.to_file("s3://bucket/outbound/folder/")
```

Comment: What error message you got on EC2 if you provide more information will very helpful for us?

Comment: I am able to see the result while print(gdf) but unable to create files on different bucket

gdfw =gdf.to_file("s3://bucket/outbound/folder/")

Comment: Do you got any error message?

Comment: I get `DataSourceError: Error opening file /vsis3/bucket-name/oath/to/file.shx for writing`. The .shx file exists but can't open for writing for some reason...